# GPU Overdraw not work with my apk on Android

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

I turn on GPU Overdraw on device or emulator, most apps can display the Overdrawings, but my app displays as normal, is there something wrong with my design?

Comment: How did you write your app? Android Java, WebView/Javascript, Unity or other third-party app creation tool?

Comment: Android java, Android Studio, all activity are extend from a base activity, the base activity's layout as below    <com.imo.view.TitleBar
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </com.imo.view.TitleBar>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> and wrapped within a linerlayout

Answer (score 3):

hardwareAccelerated should be settled to true in Androidmanifest file